# How to install second life?

Tags: install-from-source

I downloaded [Second life](http://secondlife.com/support/downloads/) from the website for Ubuntu . And I extracted the file but I cant get it to run or know how to get it to run so that I can install it right.The program is in script until I can get it to run. Can someone please tell me what to do after I extracted the file. Please try to make it simple instructions, step by step, not to great on knowing how to do computer stuff.

Comment: This question has been updated there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078071/second-life-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This question has been updated there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078071/second-life-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 6):

Follow this step by step:

- Press here to download the file: [Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686.tar.bz2](http://download.cloud.secondlife.com/Viewer_3/Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686.tar.bz2).
- Save it to your home folder(`/home/YOUR USERNAME`).
- Right click the downloaded file, select `extract here.`
- Open up a terminal.(On your keyboard: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>-)
- Typ in the terminal: `cd Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686`
- Then in the same terminal: `sudo ./install.sh`,

  - typ in your password, press enter,
  - press enter again
- Go to dash (Windows key on your keyboard, left top right button on your screen.)

  - Typ in secondlife, click on the second life icon, and voila:

[image]

Comment: The name of the file has now changed, there is a new version, Second_Life_3_7_29_301305_i686.  Maybe it would be better to point to where the download is and say to put 'cd [name of extracted file]', or something like that.

Comment: This worked for me, but as Kim Holder pointed out, you need to adjust the filename accordingly - it was "Second_Life_5_0_9_329906_i686" for me, but this will obviously change as Linden Lab release new versions.

Answer (score 3):

Using Elementary O.S, a distribution based on Ubuntu, after these packages were installed, I could run the SecondLife application as follows:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Answer (score -1):

this is how you get secondlife on Linux:

1. Download it from website
2. Extract to desired install location
3. Open terminal and type `cd /path/to/second/life` then type `ls` to display files
4. type `sudo ./install.sh`
5. type `sudo apt-get install ./secondlife`
6. type `cd /second/life/directory`
7. then type " ./secondlife