# How do I download, install and play Second Life on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: 14.04

I attempted to download Second Life for Ubuntu 14.04.3, 64-Bit, and I got no results. I tried following some other answers, but either the window just won't show up, or the Terminal wasn't following according to the answer. Can someone help me with this?

For those who want to know what instructions I tried, follow this link. I followed them and the game wouldn't show up.
[How to install second life?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579806/how-to-install-second-life)

Comment: What instructions have you tried? Please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Added a link to the instructions I followed.

Comment: The secondlife viewer is 32 bit, did you install all the necessary 32 bit libraries?  Did you try a 64 bit viewer like Kokua?  It even has voice chat working, so in some ways is more complete than the official viewer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to download extra libraries without screwing up my computer.

Answer (score 0):

For your 64 bit system, I'd first try the Kokua viewer from [kokuaviewer Downloads](http://wiki.kokuaviewer.org/wiki/Kokua/Downloads).  That should install and run on your system without problems (assuming you have the sound already working).  The voice chat feature works, but its implementation does not have Linden Labs' blessing, so may go away in the future.  In that case, you will have to switch to the approved mechanism and run the secondlife Windows voice program under wine (like you would have to do for the official viewer).

If you really want to get the necessary 32 bit libraries, here is a list from the second life bin file:

```
$ ldd do-not-directly-run-secondlife-bin
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf773d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76ef000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf763f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7635000)
    libhunspell-1.3.so.0 => not found
    libopenal.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0xf75be000)
    libalut.so.0 => not found
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf755f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf7435000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf73bb000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1 (0xf7338000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf71ed000)
    libfmodex.so => not found
    libGLOD.so => not found
    libSDL-1.2.so.0 => not found
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf712c000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf7129000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf6c33000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf6c08000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf6c03000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf6bba000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found
    libapr-1.so.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf6a42000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf69ed000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf69d0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf681a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x565c8000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf67ff000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf67d3000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf67ca000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6755000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0 (0xf6735000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf66b5000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf668e000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf6680000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xf662f000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xf6606000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf643d000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf6430000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf642c000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf6419000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf640c000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf6401000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xf63fc000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf63f8000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf63f1000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xf62b0000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf629b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf6295000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xf626e000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xf6256000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6252000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf624a000)
    libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0xf623f000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xf6219000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf6200000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf614f000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf614b000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf6140000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xf60dc000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0xf60d2000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf60aa000)
```

and the voice program:

```
$ ldd SLVoice
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf772f000)
    libortp.so => /usr/local/vm/work/Second_Life_5_0_3_324435_i686/bin/./../lib/libortp.so (0xf76fb000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/local/vm/work/Second_Life_5_0_3_324435_i686/bin/./../lib/libsndfile.so.1 (0xf76a1000)
    libvivoxsdk.so => /usr/local/vm/work/Second_Life_5_0_3_324435_i686/bin/./../lib/libvivoxsdk.so (0xf7055000)
    libvivoxplatform.so => /usr/local/vm/work/Second_Life_5_0_3_324435_i686/bin/./../lib/libvivoxplatform.so (0xf6f57000)
    libvivoxoal.so.1 => /usr/local/vm/work/Second_Life_5_0_3_324435_i686/bin/./../lib/libvivoxoal.so.1 (0xf6f0f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf6ec8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf6ebe000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf6ea5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf6ea0000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0xf6e6c000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf6e66000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6e48000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf6cd1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf6c7c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6c5f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6aa9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x5659d000)
```

Note that some libraries are missing in my setup, but they don't affect what I do.  Also, the (Linux) voice library setup is pretty useless since the libvivoxoal never got set up completely (like the Kokua setup did), so the Linux voice program can never run.  The approved voice setup is to install Windows SL under wine, and run that SLVoice under wine.  That does work successfully with the 32bit SL Linux SL viewer.