# Second Life In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: games, compatibility

I wanna play second life in my Xubuntu when I have installed without any problem but when I click on the icon doesn't appear anything... When I run it at terminal it shoots me a message that says it couldn't find gftools-2 and it say too that I need to install ia32-libs but when I try to install this libraries terminal says that it doesn't exist, then... Somebody could help me to get second life works?

**NB**: I downloaded the tar from the official page for Linux systems.

**Update**

```
$ sudo ./secondlife 
64-bit Linux detected.
Multi-arch support detected.
Running from /home/nikasha/Second_Life_5_0_9_329906_i686
 - Installing menu entries in /usr/local/share/applications
bin/do-not-directly-run-secondlife-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** Bad shutdown ($LL_RUN_ERR). ***

You are running the Second Life Viewer on a x86_64 platform.  The
most common problems when launching the Viewer (particularly
'bin/do-not-directly-run-secondlife-bin: not found' and 'error while
loading shared libraries') may be solved by installing your Linux
distribution's 32-bit compatibility packages.
For example, on Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linuxes you might run:
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl

*******************************************************
This is a BETA release of the Second Life linux client.
Thank you for testing!
Please see README-linux.txt before reporting problems.
```

So.. what happens? :O

*Solution*

OK!! with Firestorm works perfectly! Thank you so much!!

http://www.firestormviewer.org/linux/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I played Second Life (on MEPIS 11 and Kubuntu 14.04, last in 2014) the general recommendation was to use Firestorm, from Phoenix, rather than the Linden Labs viewer.  There's a 64-bit version that updates regularly, and ought to keep up with changes in Ubuntu better than the Linden version.  It's no harder to install, in my recollection, and worked better at that time.

Comment: The Kokua 64 bit viewer is another working viewer, but both it and Firestorm still use the 32 bit SLVoice binary for voice chats, so some 32 bit libs may still be necessary for full functionality.

Comment: Humm, I'll try Kokua, is that link the correct version? https://sourceforge.net/projects/kokua.team-purple.p/

Comment: Yes, I do recall having to install some alternate architecture libraries to get the sound to work when I use Firestorm.  Wasn't difficult, as I recall, and there were instructions on the Phoenix download/install page.

Comment: @NikashaVoncarstein I get the 5.1.8 kokua directly from http://wiki.kokuaviewer.org/wiki/Kokua/Downloads  The other release numberings (3.8.7, 4.2.2,...) are for the opensim viewer, I think.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum necessary for getting Second Life running (without media) in Ubuntu 18.04 is the following:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386  
sudo apt install lsb-core
```

i386 architecture is enabled already out of the box. Also run this for getting over the registery errors:

```
sudo apt install gconf2  
mkdir -p ~/.kde/share/kde4/services # for KDE desktop environments
```

Answer (score 2):

Over time the way Linux manages having both 32-bit and 64-bit packages has changed, which is why you will see outdated documentation referencing the `ia32-libs` package. You should be able to get what you want using:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libidn11:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libuuid1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libnss3:i386 libnspr4:i386 libxtst6:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libxss1:i386
```

It may need other libraries too, but the basic idea here is that you are installing `somelib:i386` since Second Life is trying to use 32-bit binaries.

Comment: I answer you up because this comments are a restritect tam, thanks for your help! :D

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libgdk-x11:i386`

Comment: Can't find the package  libgdk-x11:i386

Comment: Sorry try this: `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I tried with Firestorm and works perfectly, thanks!